# reCaptcha isnt working as intended in php

Tags: php, registration, recaptcha

I'm trying to add reCaptcha to my registration page, but i cant seem to get it to work, it keeps displaying the message that the data was entered incorrectly, the code is below:

```
<div align="center">    
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1"];

if(empty($username)) die(print '<script> alert ("Enter Username"); window.location="registration.php"; </script>');
if(empty($password)) die(print '<script> alert ("Enter Password"); window.location="registration.php"; </script>');
if($password != $password1) die(print '<script> alert ("Password doesn\'t match"); window.location="registration.php"; </script>'); 

require_once('recaptchalib.php'); // reCAPTCHA Library
$privkey = "6Ld27usSAAAAAKiYor8lnBs9fb6HOd1IK5JnTCyL"; // Private API Key
$verify = recaptcha_check_answer($privkey, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],   $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'], $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);

if ($verify!=is_valid) { 

  echo "You did not enter the correct Captcha.  Please try again.";
}
else {


$file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$string = "$username||$password";
if(!strstr($file, "$string"))
{
$myFile = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "$username||$password\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
print '<script> alert ("Registration Complete"); window.location="index.php"; </script>';
fclose($fh);
}
else
{

echo "Sorry the username: <b>$username</b> is already registered. Please use diferent username.";

}
}
}
?>
</div>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black; margin:auto">

<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; width:500px; height:400px; float: left">
<br>
<form align="center" method="post" action="registration.php" >
Username:
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br/>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br/>
<br/>
Confirm:
<input type="password" name="password1" />
<br/>
<br/>
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php'); // reCAPTCHA Library
$pubkey = "6Ld27usSAAAAAB9Zq67L28CqywwEn9RZ_7bFthm7"; // Public API Key
echo recaptcha_get_html($pubkey); // Display reCAPTCHA
?>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a feeling that my problem is in ($verify!=is_valid) but i am not sure. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `is_valid`? Is doesn't appear to be defined in your script here; also, it's not prepended with a `$` so I'm assuming that it's a constant?

Comment: What is `is_valid`? it doesn't seem to be a function call, and there's no variable with that name, so I assume PHP's interpreting it as a constant

Comment: @newfurniturey - argh! Kindly vacate my head!

Comment: it is declared in recaptchalib.php as reCaptcha is a library and that is the file for it

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs found [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php), it looks like you're not using the return value of `recaptcha_check_answer()` properly:

> **recaptcha_check_answer** returns an object that represents whether the
>   user successfully completed the challenge.
>   If **$resp->is_valid** is true then the captcha challenge was correctly completed and you should
>   continue with form processing.

Instead of `$verify != is_valid`, you should use the `is_valid` value on the returned object:

```
if ($verify->is_valid) {
    echo "You did not enter the correct Captcha. Please try again.";
} else {
    ...
```